# Redis-cli && bash find keys with empty values

Tags: bash, redis

How can i find all elements in redis which is empty
i have keys like this:

```
setting:1
setting:2
setting:442
```

etc

how can i search with redis-cli bash script command if any key contains empty value
Something like `redis-cli keys \* | xargs -L 1 redis-cli get`
with grep and check if value is empty

found solution

```
redis-cli KEYS "settings:*" | xargs -L 1 redis-cli get
```

Answer (score 1):

The notion of an empty key in Redis is non-existent - there are no empty keys in Redis. If a key "becomes" empty (e.g. a List that was popped with the final element), the key does not exist in Redis anymore. Here's an example:

```
foo@bar:~$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> exists foo
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush foo bar
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> exists foo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> lpop foo
"bar"
127.0.0.1:6379> exists foo
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379>
```